# Angular Wrap Broken Between Versions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14191/) that's running Angular 1.0.

Hover over the image, and it works fine (you'll see an overlay over the image.)

What I'm doing is wrapping the element with a container div using `.wrap(..)` function, and later binding the `mouseover` event to the container div. It works fine.

However, in Angular 1.3 like in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14190/) with ***exactly the same code***, the container div doesn't recognize my element as its child, which affects the mouseover event from being triggered.

Am I doing something wrong or is it broken in 1.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jump from Angular 1.2.x to 1.3.0 involved a few changes to jqLite. One of which was commit [#77d3e75 - fix(jqLite): clone wrapNode in jqlite/wrap](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/77d3e7544642396d868aa49b85f0c027e8057bd7#diff-8e0d9e5c18fe4f1050484080525d4367).

If you run each, the commit before that works, says 1 child exists. That commit says 0. This is intentional, though. This was to prevent unintended side-effects, and to better match JQuery's implementation.

In fact, a test assertion for your exact usage was added in that commit:

```
expect(root.children().length).toBe(0);
```

A solution to this particular case might be to change the code slightly, from:

```
el = angular.element('<div class="overlay-container"></div>');
iElement.wrap(el);
```

To:

```
iElement.wrap('<div class="overlay-container"></div>');
el = iElement.parent();
```

That said, I'm not sure why this behaviour was changed. Given that a `angular.element` was already created, it doesn't make much sense to me that another is being created.

Comment: That does the trick. Nice dig up ! Still seems to be a weird behaviour to me, but what can you do :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular.js doesn't use [semver](http://semver.org/). It means that your code can be broken by any update of angular. *(I don't see the reason why angular team creates that dependency hell)*

For each update of angular version you should check [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and update your code for each breaking change.

You can't even rely on minor version number. There are breaking changes for patch updates in changelog.

If you update your application from 1.0 to 1.3 I advise you to start from changelog, as there can be bugs that isn't visible at first. Because there is huge number of breakings (159 for me using find in browser) and most of them was between v1.0 to v1.4.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not using 1.0 myself, but was just writing something in the Fiddler and found out it didn't work when tried to use it in my project. Took me some time to find it's the `wrap` thing.